# What is type aliasing in C++?

Tags: c++

I am reading C++ 11 wikipedia page about new features and did not understand this part about type aliasing:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Template_aliases

> The using syntax can be also used as type aliasing in C++11:
>
> typedef void (*FunctionType)(double);       // Old style
> using FunctionType = void (*)(double); // New introduced syntax

What is type aliasing and what is it used for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `typedef` keyword is used to create a new name for an existing type---that is, a type alias. Every type alias that can be formed using `typedef` can also be formed using the new *alias-declaration* syntax that starts with `using`. A type alias declared using an *alias-declaration* has exactly the same effect as one declared using `typedef`.

Comment: Maybe an example would be helpful for OP.

Comment: @FilipKočica the question already contains an example.

Comment: What about usage ?